# C++ API writes Varint in different fashion to file than to socket

Tags: c#, c++, protocol-buffers

I want to ask because I find that strange: the way varint is written is depend on the target.

My simple code can write to a file or to a socket. When I write to the file the hexdump shows

> 0000000 02ac
>   0000002

When I write to the socket the C# client that reads byte by byte shows

> ac  02

the code resposible for that is:

C++ app

```
  if(connect(fd, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr))<0) {
    perror("połączenie nieudane");
    return -1;
    }

  //int fd = open("myfile", O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC);
   ZeroCopyOutputStream* raw_output = new FileOutputStream(fd);
   CodedOutputStream* coded_output = new CodedOutputStream(raw_output);

   coded_output->WriteVarint32(300);

   delete coded_output;
   delete raw_output;
   close(fd);
```

C# app

```
var str = client.GetStream();
while(str.DataAvailable) {
                b = (byte)str.ReadByte();
                Console.Write("{0:x2}  ", b);
            }
```

I thought there should be no difference. I can't explain that to myself. Do you know what is up?

Comment: Do **not** `new` everything in C++ as you would in C#. Use local variables and noone will be harmed.

Comment: I can't comment on the C++, but I can confirm that ac 02 is the correct varint encoding for 300.

Comment: For the record, with that prefix I would expect DeserializeWithLengthPrefix to work as long as the prefix-style is specified as Base128 and the field-number/tag is specified as zero.

Comment: @Xeo It seems an overkill, however, try send the varint without 'delete' - it is just NOT WORKING. I spent a few hours before I realized you **have to delete** coded_output in order to send the varint. Why is that? I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using `hexdump` (or `od`) to show the file contents, and that you don't actually have a problem ;-)

Demo:

```
$ echo -n ab > file
$ hexdump file
0000000 6261          # notice this is 'ba'
0000002
$ hexdump -C file
00000000  61 62                                             |ab|
00000002
```

Without options, hexdump will interpret the data in 16bit chunks, not byte by byte. Use the `-C` to get a per-8bit quantity output in order.

You wouldn't have this (display) problem on big-endian machine.

Comment: no .... ... . All these details are just overwhelming when you analyse API that is not well know and not thoroughly documented.